# monkey runner random generation

Tags: android, scripting, random, jython, monkeyrunner

When I want to input some character I do it like this

```
device.press("0",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

this makes input of char '0', and it works great

but the problem is I want to enter random numbers between 0 and 9 for let say 1000 times

how can I do this ? how can I play with random generation in monkeyrunner

I want randomly to choose between:

```
device.press("0",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
device.press("1",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
device.press("2",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
device.press("3",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
...
device.press("9",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

**EDIT**

I want to do this

```
device.press("Random Number between zero and nine",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
device.press("Random Number between zero and nine",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
device.press("Random Number between zero and nine",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
device.press("Random Number between zero and nine",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

...

but I need valid syntax to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as monkeyrunner runs on Jython API, try using `str(random.randint(0, 9))` in place of the `"Random Number between zero and nine"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure entirely what you're trying to do, but if what you want is something along the lines of -

```
device.press("Numberbetweenzeroandnine",MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

then I would suggest generating a random number between 0 and 9 to an integer, and passing in this integer.

Comment: Since what you need to do is simply generating a random number, I would suggest simply looking for a basic tutorial on random number generation in Java, of which there are many. You should make some research effort before posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I done 10 hours research before posting this I have made ten scrips so far and everything works just great but I could not find how to generate random numbers with monkeyrunner, are you sure that there is support for this ?